# accessing index of string but it is not giving right answer

Tags: c#

accessing the index of number through int digit = number[j], but instead of the digit it is giving a two digit number 51, 53, 54 etc. My inputs are number = 3675356291, pairlength = 5, noofdigits = 10

```
public static long Highest_multiple(string number, int pairlength, int noofdigits)
            {
                int noofpairs = (noofdigits - pairlength) + 1;
                long[] multiplied_result = new long[noofpairs];
                int p = 0;
                number.ToCharArray();
                for( int i = 0; i < noofpairs; i ++)                      // i < noofpairs so that i don't get indexoutofrange exception, as I know how many pairs will be there.
                {
                    multiplied_result[i] = 1;
                    for( int j = i; j < (pairlength + i); j ++)
                    {
                        int digit = number[j];
                        Console.WriteLine(digit);
                        multiplied_result[i] = multiplied_result[i] * digit;
                    }
                }
                long answer = multiplied_result.Max();
                return answer; 
            }
```

Comment: What do you have and what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: If I understand what you are doing, `noofpairs` should be `noofdigits / pairlength`. But you don't need `noofdigits` if you can determine that from `number`. Also, you realize `number.ToCharArray()` returns an array, it does not turn `number` into an array right? This is just a start, step through your code with the debugger and you will see what is going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at an [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/).

When you're converting a `char` to an `int` you are getting its ASCII decimal value, *not* the actual typed character.  (Try using a string made entirely of letters, you still get numbers from it.)

This:

```
int digit = number[j];
```

Should instead be [something like this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.char.getnumericvalue):

```
double digit = Char.GetNumericValue(number[j]);
```

Note that this would return `-1` for non-numeric characters.